# Grab first 20 bytes of 32-bytes input

Tags: solidity, assembly, bytes, type-casting

In solidity casting or assembly, how do I grab the first 20 bytes of this 32-bytes input: `0x00010000c900c90062fceaad00000000000000000002af416812f9bb6f2fdff5`?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be of help https://github.com/GNSPS/solidity-bytes-utils

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast the value in byte20 case i.e(bytes20(bytes32)).